# Singular linked list become circular list when passed to a function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a linked list by using C++ and then print out the reversed one.

For example:
the original list is 1->2->3
after reversion: 3->2->1

But when I tried to print out the reversed linked list, 3->2->1 became a circular linked list like 3<->2

Followings are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class List{
public:
    int value;
    List *next;
    List(int);
    List(int, List *);
};

List::List(int v){
    value = v;
    next = NULL;
}

List::List(int v, List *ne){
    value = v;
    next = ne;
}

string IntToString(int val){
    stringstream temp;
    temp<<val;
    return temp.str();
}

void print(List *l){
    string output= "";
    while(l->next != NULL){
        output+=(IntToString(l->value)+"-->");
        l = l->next;
    }
    output+=(IntToString(l->value)+"-->NULL");
    cout<<output<<endl;
}

List reverse(List L){
    if(L.next == NULL) return L;
    List remain = reverse(*(L.next));
    List *current = &remain;
    while(current->next != NULL)
        current = (current->next);
    L.next = NULL;
    current->next = &L;
    //print(remain);
    return remain;
}

List copy(List l){
    return l;
}

int main() {
    List L3(3);
    List L2(2, &L3);
    List L1(1, &L2);
    List L4 = reverse(L1);
    print(&L4);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to point out to you that a `list` containing a pointer to `another list` is *conceptually wrong*.

Create a list node class seperately, e.g.

```
struct ListNode {
    int value;
    Node *next;
};
```

Then your `List` becomes,

```
class List {
    ...
    ListNode *head;
    ...
};
```

Now onto reversing. In the method `List reverse( List L )`, ***L is simply a local variable***. *It goes out of scope after*,

```
    return remain;
} // Here the scope of L ends
```

So it is logically incorrect to return a `List` whose `next` value is location of L,

```
current->next = &L;
return remain; // remain is equal to *current and current->next = &L
```

This causes ***undefined behavior*** in your implementation.

EDIT: I have some free time, so I came up with [this implementation](http://pastebin.com/LCC6sEru). It uses the same algorithm although modifies the *original list* on which it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think your reverse algorithm is correct, but `remain` is a local variable, which is invalid after return, therefore L4 will contain invalid pointer. Change the signature of `reverse()` to take and return `List *`.

```
List *reverse(List *L){
    if(L->next == NULL) return L;
    List *remain = reverse(L->next);
    List *current = remain;
    while(current->next != NULL)
        current = (current->next);
    L->next = NULL;
    current->next = L;
    //print(remain);
    return remain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your `reverse()` function you are creating an object on the stack called `remain` and insert this into your list. This can't work: this object will go out of scope once your return from the function (the original objects in `main()` have the same problem but you don't try to use them after you left `main()`). Also, your `reverse()` function seems to have quadratic performance while it should be linear. I think something like this would do the trick:

```
List* reverse(List* head) {
    List* tail(0);
    while (head) {
        List* tmp(head);
        head = head->next;
        tmp->next = tail;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    return tail;
}
```

The above implementation also avoids the recursion.